# My cursor frequently disappears, none of the solutions I found works

Tags: cursor

My workstation runs Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
It has an AMD A4-7300 APU with Radeon HD Graphics x 2 .
Since a few weeks the cursor frequently disappears. (Completely).
One of the solutions I found was to get the launcher by Alt+f1,
that worked once but no more: The launcher icon flickers, but does not
launch the launcher.
Now I powercycle, which I definitely do not like to do.
I completely reloaded Ubuntu a few months ago. The problem started a few
weeks ago. Since then I updated Ubuntu, did not help.16

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your display manager... Also looking into some of your system logs sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I know SEVERAL people that have this same issue. They temporarily fix it by pressing the power off button so it asks if you would like to logout.. reboot.. etc. Then it should reappear. I have also seen that opening a terminal sometimes fixes it as well. But note that this is temporary.